# Exporting textfiles from VCorpus including original file names in R

Tags: r, export, filenames, tm, corpus

I'm quite new to R and currently working on a project for my studies (readability vs performance of annual reports). I've literally screened hundreds of posts but could not find a proper solution. So, I'm stuck and need you're help.

My **goal** is to tm roughly 1000 text documents and **export the edited texts from the VCorpus into a folder, including the original file names**.

So far I managed to import & do (some) text mining:

```
### folder of txt files    

dest <- ("C:\\Xpdf_pdftotext\\TestCorpus")

### create a Corpus in R

docs <- VCorpus(DirSource(dest))

### do some text mining of the txt-documents

for (j in seq(docs)) {
  docs[[j]] <- gsub("\\d", "", docs[[j]])
  docs[[j]] <- gsub("\\b[A-z]\\b{3}", "", docs[[j]])
  docs[[j]] <- gsub("\\t", "", docs[[j]])
}
```

Export each file in the Corpus with its original file names.
works for 1 file, when assigning a new name:

```
writeLines(as.character(docs[1]), con="text1.txt")
```

I've found the command for the meta ID in a post, but I don't know how to include it in my code

```
docs[[1]]$meta$id
```

**How can I efficiently export the edited textfiles from the VCorpus including their original file names?**

Thanks for helping

Comment: Is my problem that simple or remains a conundrum for many? - any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is very simple.

If you have a corpus loaded as you did, you can write the whole corpus to disk in one command with using `writeCorpus`. The meta tag id needs to be filled in, but in your case that is already done how you loaded the data.

If we take the `crude` dataset as an example, the id's are already included:

```
library(tm)
data("crude")
crude <- as.VCorpus(crude)
# bit of textcleaning
crude <- tm_map(crude, stripWhitespace)
crude <- tm_map(crude, removePunctuation)
crude <- tm_map(crude, content_transformer(tolower))
crude <- tm_map(crude, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

#write to disk in subfolder data
writeCorpus(crude, path = "data/")

# check files
dir("data/")
[1] "127.txt" "144.txt" "191.txt" "194.txt" "211.txt" "236.txt" "237.txt" "242.txt" "246.txt" "248.txt" "273.txt" "349.txt" "352.txt"
[14] "353.txt" "368.txt" "489.txt" "502.txt" "543.txt" "704.txt" "708.txt"
```

The files from the `crude` dataset are written to disk with the id's as filenames.